# OpenCV: reading frames from VideoCapture advances the video to bizarrely wrong location

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video, video-processing

(I will put a 500 reputation bounty on this question as soon as it's eligible - unless the question got closed.)

**Problem in one sentence**

Reading frames from a `VideoCapture` advances the video much further than it's supposed to.

**Explanation**

I need to read and analyze frames from a 100 fps (according to `cv2` and VLC media player) video between certain time-intervals. In the minimal example that follows I am trying to read all the frames for the first ten seconds of a three minute video.

I am creating a `cv2.VideoCapture` object from which I read frames until the  desired position in milliseconds is reached. In my actual code each frame is analyzed, but that fact is irrelevant in order to showcase the error.

Checking the current frame and millisecond position of the `VideoCapture` after reading the frames yields correct values, so the `VideoCapture` **thinks** it is at the right position - but it is not. Saving an image of the last read frame reveals that my iteration is grossly overshooting the destination time **by over two minutes**.

What's even more bizarre is that if I manually set the millisecond position of the capture with `VideoCapture.set` to 10 seconds (the same value `VideoCapture.get` returns after reading the frames) and save an image, the video is at (almost) the right position!

**Demo video file**

In case you want to run the MCVE, you need the demo.avi video file.
You can download it [**HERE**](https://workupload.com/file/Q4ELvBC).

**MCVE**

This MCVE is carefully crafted and commented. Please leave a comment under the question if anything remains unclear.

If you are using OpenCV 3 you have to replace all instances of `cv2.cv.CV_` with `cv2.`. (The problem occurs in both versions for me.)

```
import cv2

# set up capture and print properties
print 'cv2 version = {}'.format(cv2.__version__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi')
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('initial attributes: fps = {}, pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(fps, pos_msec, pos_frames))

# get first frame and save as picture
_, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('first_frame.png', frame)

# advance 10 seconds, that's 100*10 = 1000 frames at 100 fps
for _ in range(1000):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # in the actual code, the frame is now analyzed

# save a picture of the current frame
cv2.imwrite('after_iteration.png', frame)

# print properties after iteration
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('attributes after iteration: pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(pos_msec, pos_frames))

# assert that the capture (thinks it) is where it is supposed to be
# (assertions succeed)
assert pos_frames == 1000 + 1 # (+1: iteration started with second frame)
assert pos_msec == 10000 + 10

# manually set the capture to msec position 10010
# note that this should change absolutely nothing in theory
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 10010)

# print properties  again to be extra sure
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('attributes after setting msec pos manually: pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(pos_msec, pos_frames))

# save a picture of the next frame, should show the same clock as
# previously taken image - but does not
_, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('after_setting.png', frame)
```

**MCVE output**

The `print` statements produce the following output.

> cv2 version = 2.4.9.1
>   initial attributes: fps = 100.0, pos_msec = 0.0, pos_frames = 0.0
>   attributes after reading: pos_msec = 10010.0, pos_frames = 1001.0
>   attributes after setting msec pos manually: pos_msec = 10010.0, pos_frames = 1001.0

As you can see, all properties have the expected values.

`imwrite` saves the following pictures.

first_frame.png
[image: first_frame.png]

after_iteration.png
[image: after_iteration.png]

after_setting.png
[image: after_setting.png]

You can see the problem in the second picture. The target of 9:26:15 (real time clock in picture) is missed by over two minutes. Setting the target time manually (third picture) sets the video to (almost) the correct position.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

**Tried so far**

cv2 2.4.9.1 @ Ubuntu 16.04
cv2 2.4.13 @ Scientific Linux 7.3 (three computers)
cv2 3.1.0 @ Scientific Linux 7.3 (three computers)

Creating the capture with

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi', apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

and

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi', apiPreference=cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

in OpenCV 3 (version 2 does not seem to have the `apiPreference` argument).
Using `cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER` takes extremely long (about 2-3 minutes to run the MCVE) but both api-preferences produce the same incorrect images.

When using `ffmpeg`  directly to read frames (credit to [this](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/) tutorial) the correct output images are produced.

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp
import pylab

# video properties
path = './demo.avi'
resolution = (593, 792)
framesize = resolution[0]*resolution[1]*3

# set up pipe
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"
command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
           '-i', path,
           '-f', 'image2pipe',
           '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

# read first frame and save as image
raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(framesize)
image = np.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape(resolution[0], resolution[1], 3)
pylab.imshow(image)
pylab.savefig('first_frame_ffmpeg_only.png')
pipe.stdout.flush()

# forward 1000 frames
for _ in range(1000):
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(framesize)
    pipe.stdout.flush()

# save frame 1001
image = np.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape(resolution[0], resolution[1], 3)
pylab.imshow(image)
pylab.savefig('frame_1001_ffmpeg_only.png')

pipe.terminate()
```

This produces the correct result! (Correct timestamp 9:26:15)

frame_1001_ffmpeg_only.png:
[image: frame_1001_ffmpeg_only.png]

**Additional information**

In the comments I was asked for my `cvconfig.h` file. I only seem to have this file for cv2 version 3.1.0 under `/opt/opencv/3.1.0/include/opencv2/cvconfig.h`.

[**HERE**](https://pastebin.com/dK9AFfan) is a paste of this file.

In case it helps, I was able to extract the following video information with `VideoCapture.get`.

> brightness             0.0
>   contrast               0.0
>   convert_rgb            0.0
>   exposure               0.0
>   format                 0.0
>   fourcc                 1684633187.0
>   fps                    100.0
>   frame_count            18000.0
>   frame_height           593.0
>   frame_width            792.0
>   gain                   0.0
>   hue                    0.0
>   mode                   0.0
>   openni_baseline        0.0
>   openni_focal_length    0.0
>   openni_frame_max_depth 0.0
>   openni_output_mode     0.0
>   openni_registration    0.0
>   pos_avi_ratio          0.01
>   pos_frames             0.0
>   pos_msec               0.0
>   rectification          0.0
>   saturation             0.0

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried with any other libraries? For e.g. [`skvideo`](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html)?

Comment: What platform? Why such old version of OpenCV? This is damn weird, I wouldn't at all expect `read()` from a file to skip frames...

Comment: BTW, I've tried this locally, on Win10 with Python 2.7.5 and OpenCV 2.4.11, and both after_ images show a timestamp of `9:26:15`. It's intersting that even your `after_setting.png` is 2 seconds off the desired time. It could be a bug in OpenCV, or more likely with whatever library is used in your case to decode the AVI file...

Comment: how were your videos recorded?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds no, not yet. I need to use OpenCV because I already wrote a medium sized Python adapter/framework that subclasses `cv2.VideoCapture` (all of that is omitted in the MCVE). I'd rather not have all that work undone.

Comment: @DanMašek I am using Scientific Linux release 7.3 at work and an Ubuntu flavor at another computer. I also tried using cv2 version 3.1.0, but the problem stays exactly the same. In order to run the MCVE with OpenCV 3 replace all instances of `cv2.cv.CV_` with `cv2.`.

Comment: @DanMašek I am very grateful that you went through the work of downloading the video and running the code yourself. The fact that it seems to work fine for you is valuable information. "more likely with whatever library is used in your case to decode the AVI file" <- Can you tell me how I would find out which library decodes the AVI? Thanks!

Comment: @Micka the videos were recorded on a Windows 7 machine with the software Camstudio. The video is the live-output of a camera and I captured the screen region where the video shows with Camstudio.

Comment: @timgeb The following links *may* be helpful: [1](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html), [2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a85b55cf6a4a50451367ba96b65218ba1), [3](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d). Specifically 1 says "Check in `opencv2/cvconfig.h` to know which APIs are currently available (e.g. `HAVE_MSMF`, `HAVE_VFW`, `HAVE_LIBV4L`, etc...)."

Comment: @timgeb did you compile OpenCV with the `ffmpeg` library? You can try reading the frames with `ffmpeg` directly ([tutorial here](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/)) to see if you get similar skips or not, and you can specify to use the `ffmpeg` library in OpenCV for `VideoCapture` with `cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi', apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`. Try it out and report back!

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I don't know how OpenCV was compiled. I added my `cvconfig.h` file in the "Additional info" part of my question. Using `ffmpeg` directly  with the tutorial you provided leads to correct images. I added it under the section "Tried so far". Using `cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi', apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)` does still produce the wrong images with the MCVE.

Comment: @timgeb I would probably try to recompile OpenCV and make sure `ffmpeg` is built with it. Other than that I'm out of my expertise here. Hope you can get a working solution, it's definitely a bizarre issue.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds thanks for your help, I'll try that next.

Comment: Reproduced under Ubuntu 16.04 with default OpenCV (cv2 2.4.9.1).

Comment: @Leon Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your video file data contains just 1313 non-duplicate frames (i.e. between 7 and 8 frames per second of duration):

```
$ ffprobe -i demo.avi -loglevel fatal -show_streams -count_frames|grep frame
has_b_frames=0
r_frame_rate=100/1
avg_frame_rate=100/1
nb_frames=18000
nb_read_frames=1313        # !!!
```

Converting the avi file with `ffmpeg` reports 16697 duplicate frames (for some reason 10 additional frames are added and 16697=18010-1313).

```
$ ffmpeg -i demo.avi demo.mp4
...
frame=18010 fps=417 Lsize=3705kB time=03:00.08 bitrate=168.6kbits/s dup=16697
#                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
...
```

> BTW, thus converted video (`demo.mp4`) is devoid of the problem being
>   discussed, that is OpenCV processes it correctly.

In this case the duplicate frames are not physically present in the avi file, instead each duplicate frame is represented by an instruction to repeat the previous frame. This can be checked as follows:

```
$ ffplay -loglevel trace demo.avi
...
[ffplay_crop @ 0x7f4308003380] n:16 t:2.180000 pos:1311818.000000 x:0 y:0 x+w:792 y+h:592
[avi @ 0x7f4310009280] dts:574 offset:574 1/100 smpl_siz:0 base:1000000 st:0 size:81266
video: delay=0.130 A-V=0.000094
    Last message repeated 9 times
video: delay=0.130 A-V=0.000095
video: delay=0.130 A-V=0.000094
video: delay=0.130 A-V=0.000095
[avi @ 0x7f4310009280] dts:587 offset:587 1/100 smpl_siz:0 base:1000000 st:0 size:81646
[ffplay_crop @ 0x7f4308003380] n:17 t:2.320000 pos:1393538.000000 x:0 y:0 x+w:792 y+h:592
video: delay=0.140 A-V=0.000091
    Last message repeated 4 times
video: delay=0.140 A-V=0.000092
    Last message repeated 1 times
video: delay=0.140 A-V=0.000091
    Last message repeated 6 times
...
```

In the above log, frames with actual data are represented by the lines starting with "`[avi @ 0xHHHHHHHHHHH]`". The "`video: delay=xxxxx A-V=yyyyy`" messages indicate that the last frame must be displayed for `xxxxx` more seconds.

`cv2.VideoCapture()` skips such duplicate frames, reading only frames that have real data. Here is the corresponding (though, slightly edited) [code from the 2.4 branch of opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L856) (note, BTW, that underneath ffmpeg is used, which I verified by running python under gdb and setting a breakpoint on `CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame`):

```cpp
bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame()
{
    ...
    int count_errs = 0;
    const int max_number_of_attempts = 1 << 9; // !!!
    ...
    // get the next frame
    while (!valid)
    {
        ...
        int ret = av_read_frame(ic, &packet);
        ...        
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(video_st->codec, picture, &got_picture, &packet);
        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(got_picture)
        {
            //picture_pts = picture->best_effort_timestamp;
            if( picture_pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE_ )
                picture_pts = packet.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE_ && packet.pts != 0 ? packet.pts : packet.dts;
            frame_number++;
            valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // So, if the next frame doesn't have picture data but is
            // merely a tiny instruction telling to repeat the previous
            // frame, then we get here, treat that situation as an error
            // and proceed unless the count of errors exceeds 1 billion!!!
            if (++count_errs > max_number_of_attempts)
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so apparently `ffmpeg` returns the duplicate frames, but the `VideoCapture` ignores them. Do you have any idea how to either force the `VideoCapture` to duplicate the missing frames or how to get correct values for `fps` and/or `pos_msec` such that in my actual program iterating to a specific `pos_msec` does not advance the video too far? Outside of the MCVE I need to advance the video to a specific position, and I do so by checking against the `pos_msec`.

Comment: (I'm hesitant to prematurely accept your answer yet because it contains the source of the problem for which I am thankful, but no fix yet)

Comment: @timgeb That's ok, don't hurry. I plan to elaborate the answer with a way how to tackle such a situation.

Comment: As  a sidenote, it's weird that @DanMašek was not able to reproduce the problem under Windows 10, apparently the `VideoCapture` has a different policy regarding duplicate frames here?!

Comment: @timgeb I tracked down the code in OpenCV that can be blamed for this problem, but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any workaround for it other than somehow piping the input file through `ffmpeg` so that it can materialize all duplicate frames or drop them and put correct timestamps on the remaining frames.

Comment: I now have a very good answer with a solution (convert the video) and another very good answer which explains the source of the problem. Unfortunately, I can't split the bounty (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) meta question). I'm waiting a little longer such that you have time to add the missing piece. I'd be fine with either converting my video (command line solution preferred) or somehow open a `VideoCapture` with input from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Apparently there's a solution [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28744/python-cv2videocapture-from-subprocesspipe/) for piping a `ffmpeg` stream to a `VideoCapture`, but the solution is for windows. I also don't know if the standard `VideoCapture` features would still work (e.g. skipping to specific positions).

Comment: @timgeb If you are OK converting your videos, then my answer contains a simple way to do that: `ffmpeg -i demo.avi demo.mp4` (you may need to provide some additional options, if you want to tweak certain conversion settings, e.g. quality). I verified that with thus converted `demo.mp4` used as an input to your script `after_iteration.png` corresponds to the correct time.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that the MCVE works after the conversion with ffmpeg :) (please edit that into your answer such that future readers don't have to go through the comments). I'm surprised that the filesize drastically goes down from 107 to 3.7 MB. I'll play with the flags a little. (edit: -crf <low value> does the trick)

Comment: @timgeb I didn't even think that converting the video might be an option, until the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551037/6394138) was posted. I added a note to the answer. And thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: I reproduced your problem on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine with OpenCV 2.4.13, noticed that the codec used in your video (FourCC CVID) seems to be rather old (according to this [post](http://www.codeccodecs.com/fourcc-cvid-t255.html) from 2011), and after converting the video to codec MJPG (aka M-JPEG or Motion JPEG) your MCVE worked.  Of course, Leon (or others) may post a fix for OpenCV, which may be the better solution for your case.

I initially tried the conversion using

```
ffmpeg -i demo.avi -vcodec mjpeg -an demo_mjpg.avi
```

and

```
avconv -i demo.avi -vcodec mjpeg -an demo_mjpg.avi
```

(both also on a 16.04 box).  Interestingly, both produced "broken" videos.  E.g., when jumping to frame 1000 using Avidemux, there in no real-time clock!  Also, the converted videos were only about 1/6 of the original size, which is strange since M-JPEG is a very simple compression.  (Each frame is JPEG-compressed independently.)

Using Avidemux to convert `demo.avi` to M-JPEG produced a video on which the MCVE worked.  (I used the Avidemux GUI for the conversion.)  The size of the converted video is about 3x the original size.  Of course, it may also be possible to do the original recording using a codec that is supported better on Linux.  If you need to jump to specific frames in the video in your application, M-JPEG may be the best option.  Otherwise, H.264 compresses much better.  Both are well-supported in my experience and the only codes I have seen implemented directly on webcams (H.264 only on high-end ones).

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, your conversion with Avidemux "physically" adds the frames which in the current video are only represented as repeat instructions? Could you please tell me how to do the conversion? Preferably via the command line (but GUI is ok too).

Comment: I now have a very good answer with a solution (convert the video) and another very good answer which explains the source of the problem. Unfortunately, I can't split the bounty (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) meta question). I'm waiting a little longer such that you have time to add the missing piece. I'd be fine with either converting my video (commnd line solution preferred) or somehow open a `VideoCapture` with input from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I just tried to convert the video to mjpeg with `avidemux3_qt4`. The video got smaller (17 MB) and the problem in the MCVE persisted. So I really need to know what you did exactly. Thanks again.

Comment: Here what I did on my 12.04 box: right-clicked demo.avi, opened with Avidemux (GTK+) (version 2.5.4), in "Copy" drop-down on left-hand side, select "M-JPEG" instead, click Save.  I just repeated this and it still works.  :)  Will see whether I can get command-line to work.  Avidemux works so-so w.r.t. command line in my experience.

Comment: Re: repeat instructions, I have not checked what Avidemux does.

Comment: I only have "Mjpeg Encoder" available in this drop down menu. Saving produces a 17 MB video file that still errors with my code. I'll try again tomorrow, out of ideas for now.

Comment: Will look into this a little more tonight.  One option would be you write your own converter extending your ffmpeg code a little.  OpenCV 2.4 (but not 3.X) writes very nice M-JPEGs; I have used this a lot for my work.

Comment: That sounds promising. I can record any future videos such that they don't lie about their fps, but sadly I absolutely need to analyze my existing videos (even if their true framerate is much lower than what I expected).

Comment: Added some sample code from a video converter I wrote that writes M-JPEGs.  Back to research until tonight...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146800/discussion-between-ulrich-stern-and-timgeb).

Comment: Just tried your `ffmpeg` code on my 12.04 and 16.04 boxes and it failed without writing images, so I cannot easily extend it with video writing.  Did you try an older Avidemux?  I just tried conversion with Avidemux 2.5.6 on Windows and got an AVI on which your MCVE worked.

Comment: For now `ffmpeg -i in.avi out.mp4 -crf 0` works alright, although some quality is lost. I'll try different codecs or programs along the way if the need arises. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: You are welcome.  I saw the comments about video conversion under Leon's answer too late.  `ffmpeg -i in.avi out.mp4 -crf 0` works for me, too, so I am somewhat surprised the `ffmpeg` command in my answer did not work.

Answer (score -1):

As you said :

> When using ffmpeg directly to read frames (credit to this tutorial) the correct output images are produced.

Is it normal because you define a 
`framesize = resolution[0]*resolution[1]*3`

then reuse it when read : 
`pipe.stdout.read(framesize)`

So in my opinion you have to update each:

```
_, frame = cap.read()
```

to

```
_, frame = cap.read(framesize)
```

Assuming the resolution is identical, final code version will be:

```
import cv2

# set up capture and print properties
print 'cv2 version = {}'.format(cv2.__version__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('demo.avi')
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('initial attributes: fps = {}, pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(fps, pos_msec, pos_frames))

resolution = (593, 792) #here resolution 
framesize = resolution[0]*resolution[1]*3 #here framesize

# get first frame and save as picture
_, frame = cap.read( framesize ) #update to get one frame
cv2.imwrite('first_frame.png', frame)

# advance 10 seconds, that's 100*10 = 1000 frames at 100 fps
for _ in range(1000):
    _, frame = cap.read( framesize ) #update to get one frame
    # in the actual code, the frame is now analyzed

# save a picture of the current frame
cv2.imwrite('after_iteration.png', frame)

# print properties after iteration
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('attributes after iteration: pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(pos_msec, pos_frames))

# assert that the capture (thinks it) is where it is supposed to be
# (assertions succeed)
assert pos_frames == 1000 + 1 # (+1: iteration started with second frame)
assert pos_msec == 10000 + 10

# manually set the capture to msec position 10010
# note that this should change absolutely nothing in theory
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 10010)

# print properties  again to be extra sure
pos_msec = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
pos_frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
print ('attributes after setting msec pos manually: pos_msec = {}, pos_frames = {}'
      .format(pos_msec, pos_frames))

# save a picture of the next frame, should show the same clock as
# previously taken image - but does not
_, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('after_setting.png', frame)
```

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't change anything.

Comment: I tried your solution and the output-images are the same as before.